# Помогите пожалуйста сделать постраничный вывод

Tags: php

вот мой код пожалуйста помогите мне сделать постраничный вывод

```
<?php
include("db_connection.php"); 
if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
    $sqlQuery = "
        SELECT * FROM `news` 
            WHERE `id_category` = ".$_GET['cat_id'].";
    ";
}else{
    $sqlQuery = "
        SELECT * FROM `news`;
    ";
}
$sql = mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $rows[] = $r;
}

foreach($rows as $row){
?>
<h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $row['small_text']; ?></p>
<h3>Автор: <?php echo $row['author']; ?> </h3>
<h6>Дата: <?php echo $row['data']; ?></h6>
<a href="/news.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Читать Дальше</a>
<hr/>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

У тебя не правильная реализация, или же ты не дописал. Скрипт должен принимать гет-параметр, который указывает, на какой странице пользователь находится. К примеру `$_GET['page'];`
Так же должна быть переменная, указывающая, сколько элементов на странице.

```
$pageCount = 10;
```

Вычисляем, с какой записи начинать выборку для запроса:

```
$start = $pageCount * $_GET['page'];
```

Кондишн запроса должен выглядить примерно так:

SELECT ... WHERE  ... ORDER BY category_id LIMIT $start, $pageCount